# How to Catch and Handle Multer Errors to Prevent Node.js Program from Crashing?

Tags: node.js, middleware, multer, koa, koa2

I'm using Multer for file uploads in my koa application. When the uploaded file does not meet the specified mimetype or size limit, Multer throws a MulterError, which causes my program to crash. I've tried using async/await, promise.catch(), and app.on("error") to catch these errors, but none seem to work effectively.

````
const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (file.mimetype === "image/jpeg" || file.mimetype === "image/png") {
    cb(null, true); 
  } else {
    cb(new Error('The file format is incorrect!'), false);
  }
};
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    const targetDir = `${uploadPath}`;
    if (!fs.existsSync(targetDir)) {
      fs.mkdirSync(targetDir, { recursive: true });
    }
    cb(null, targetDir);
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, `${Date.now()}-${file.originalname}`);
  },
});
const upload = multer({
  storage,
  limits: {
    fileSize: 200,
  },
  fileFilter
}).single("avatar");
const uploadHandle = async (ctx, next) => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  upload(ctx, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      reject(err);
      return ctx.app.emit("error", err, ctx);
     } else {
         resolve(ctx.file);
       }
  });
 })
}```
````